# Callback at certain times during audio playback

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, callback, core-audio

Is it possible to play an audio file from the user's ipod library and have a callback occur whenever the player reaches a certain time point ? I need it to be very accurate, so simply using methods like `currentPlaybackTime` might not be enough because float equality is inaccurate. I could use the `A - B < Epsilon` float check, but is there a better, more accurate way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can target iOS 4.0 or hight, try using AVPlayer.  Then you will be able to use

```
- (id)addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:(NSArray *)times queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(void))block
```

which takes an array of NSValues for CMTimes and will run the contents of the block each time one of the boundary times is hit.  (Beware of some behavior like, if you pause the audio file inside of the block, the callback will fire *again* when you unpause it).

Since CMTime is not a float, I think this will be more accurate than checking for the currentTime repeatedly.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the fast reply. This looks like the method I need.